# ArrayAdapter and Spinner getting null pointer exception

Tags: android, arrays, list, nullpointerexception, spinner

I am trying to add items to my spinner but i am getting

12-06 15:44:13.828: E/AndroidRuntime(763): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 15:44:13.828: E/AndroidRuntime(763): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050004 type #0x12 is not valid

```
Spinner options;
private String spinnerarray[4];


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fluidscreen);

    options = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.options);

    spinnerarray[0] = "Water";
    spinnerarray[1] = "Gatorade/Powerade";
    spinnerarray[2] = "Soda";
    spinnerarray[3] = "Other";

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.id.textView1, spinnerarray);
    options.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you start adding elements to the array, do:

```
spinnerarray = new String[4];
```

That is needed for allocating the memory for your String elements, without it you will get *NullPointerException*

If you have a resource problem, change your *R.id.textView1* that you specify for *ArrayAdapter*  to

```
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
```

This will reference androids default TextView element
That is a good design feature if you are willing to use a simple TextView android widget without creating any fancy View for storing your Spinner schoice

Comment: I made the change but it is saying my resource is not valid

Comment: 12-06 15:44:13.828: E/AndroidRuntime(763): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-06 15:44:13.828: E/AndroidRuntime(763): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f050004 type #0x12 is not valid